# About Eyes & Hair rigging problems

Tags: rigging

I'd try to do rigging for my character. But how to handle the eyes and hair? Should I join them to the main body and then do rig or what?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let the eyes as a separated meshes.
You can create a main rig for your body, and on the bone you will set for the head, you can parent the eyes (so they will follow head moves). Once this is done, you will be able to create separated bones to control each of your eyes.

Here is a useful tutorial on how to set the eyes bones with an existing body rig.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xSsav9wlDwI

Answer (score 0):

Another solution than B.Pader's is to join the eyes and hair to the character object (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>), create 2 bones for the eyes, parent them to the head bone, and assign the eye meshes to 2 vertex groups that have the same name as the eye bones. For the hair, assign it to the vertex group that has the name of the bone that controls the head.